# HashMap.get() возвращает null

Tags: java

Долго я гуглил в поисках решения, узнал что для правильной работы HashMap нужно переопределить equals() и hashCode(), не особо помогло.

```
public class Content {
    public static HashMap<int[], Test> test = new HashMap<int[], Test>();
}

public class Test {
int x;
public Test(int x){
    this.x = x;
    Content.test.put(new int[] {x,x}, this);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Test)) return false;

    Test test = (Test) o;

    if (x != test.x) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return x;
}
}

public class Main {

public Main(){
    new Test(4);
    System.out.println(Content.test.get(new int[] {4,4}));
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
}
}
```

Собственно объекты вставляются, но не выводятся.

Comment: зачем вам массив интов если вы его не юзаете?

Comment: Пример же, максимально точно подогнал под ту конструкцию которая у меня в программе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте

```
System.out.println(new int[] {4, 4}.hashCode());
System.out.println(new int[] {4, 4}.hashCode());
```

и вы увидите, что hashCode возвращает разные значения. Вот вам и ответ, почему HashMap.get не находит значение по ключу.

Comment: Задумывался над этим, но не поверил сам себе. А как тогда поступать? Получается я у примитивов не переопределю метод, надо обязательно класс создавать?

Comment: Ох, я походу понял, переопределение нужно для ключа а не для значения, правильно?

Comment: Да, для ключа, конечно.

Comment: Лучше ключ упаковать в класс-обёртку, а то `hashCode()` для массива не переопределить.